# ошибка кодировки в pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Хотел скомпилировать код в `exe`.
Пишу

```
pyinstaller -F name_programm.py
```

, но увы.

Вот код ошибки:

> File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pyinsta ller-script.py", line 
>       1 SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe0' in file C:\Users\Админ\AppData\ 
>       Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py on line 1, but n o encoding declared; 
>       see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в первой строке кода использовать такой комментарий:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```